# Go: range and len of multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, go, range, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to use range and len on a multidimensional array?

Either with var a [3]int8 or

```
package main

func main () {    
        var a [3][5]int8

        for h := range a {
                println(h)
        }
        println(len(a))
}
```

Both produce

`0
1
2
3`

?

Thanks to dystroy's answer, here's an example of writing and reading a 3-dimensional array i was able to adapt (posting here because I had much trouble finding any examples of this, so maybe this will help someone else):

```
package main
func main() {
    var a [3][5][7]uint8

    //write values to array
    for x, b := range a {
        for y, c := range b {
            for z, _ := range c {
                    a[x][y][z] = uint8(x*100+y*10+z)
                }
        }   
    }

    //read values from array
    for _, h := range a {
        for _, i := range h {
            for _, j := range i {
                print(j, "\t")
            }
            println()
        }
        println()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Go as in most languages, what you call a multidimensional array is an array of arrays. The `len` operator only gives you the length of the "external" array.

Maybe the var declaration could be clearer for you if you see it as

```
var a [3]([5]int8)
```

which also compiles. It's an array of size 3 whose elements are arrays of size 5 of int8.

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    var a [3][5]int8
    for _, h := range a {
        fmt.Println(len(h)) // each one prints 5
    }
    fmt.Println(len(a))  // prints 3, the length of the external array
}
```

outputs

```
5
5
5
3
```

To loop safely through the whole matrix, you can do this :

```
for _, h := range a {
    for _, cell := range h {
        fmt.Print(cell, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

If you need to change the content, you may do

```
    for i, cell := range h { // i is the index, cell the value
        h[i] = 2 * cell
    }
```

Comment: what is a nice way of looping through a multidimensional array's contents, if/when size of the array isn't known/remembered? 2 loops based on `len(a)` and `_,var:=range a` ? Does the way using range scale for 3 (or more) dimensional arrays as in `_,_,var:=range a` ?

Comment: Thank you for the example, i couldn't find anywhere.

Comment: Can that loop be modified to assign values to array elements?

Comment: Yes, use the `for i, h := range a` construct and do `a[i]=something`

Comment: Thank you so much, go arrays actually start making sense to me now :)

Comment: To find the length of multidimensional array, you could add :
const length = len(a) * len(a[5])
it will output length of array a = 15  
len(a[5]) -> as 5 is the size of all inner arrays

Answer (score 3):

The solution with range is already provided so i'll talk about how to use length (len) to go through a multi-dimesional array in golang.

So if u have an array `arr[][]` :

`[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]`

Now the `len(arr)` will output = 2.

while `len(arr[1]) will output = 3`.

Sample code is provided here : https://play.golang.org/p/XerzPhkQrhU

Answer (score 0):

No, the first one produces 0,1,2 ( index of in the range )

http://play.golang.org/p/0KrzTRWzKO

And the second one produces 3 ( the length of the array ).

http://play.golang.org/p/0esKFqQZL0

In both cases you're using the outermost array.

Comment: It was shorthand for "Either with var a [3]int8 or var a [3][5]int8".